# Drupal 8 - Accessing _entity in content variable in template to print out content

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I am trying to print out a view, field by field so I can apply my style to it and customize the look of it.

When I copy over the views-view-unformatted--MY-TEMPLATE.html.twig
I can see these variables in the default view:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a view of unformatted rows.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - title: The title of this group of rows. May be empty.
 * - rows: A list of the view's row items.
 *   - attributes: The row's HTML attributes.
 *   - content: The row's content.
 * - view: The view object.
 * - default_row_class: A flag indicating whether default classes should be
 *   used on rows.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
```

After using {{ kint(content) }}, I can see that I have an 
_entity field as show
[image]

However I can't figure out how to print out those specific fields, or even use Kint to find out how to separate them. I've tried doing something like so:

```
{{ kint(content._entity) }}
```

to no avail, and a tonne of other ways of trying to print it out.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I solved my problem by using a different views template, but I believe I should have been able to do it this way, so I will keep the question open.

Comment: Have you tried content.entity ?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because Content._entity is a node entity, not a renderable array that you can print.